# Is the NOON state entangled even if $N=1$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-entanglement, identical-particles

Let $\mathcal{H}\cong\mathbb{C}^2$ be the Hilbert space of states of a single particle. Let $\{|\psi_A\rangle, \psi_B\rangle\}$ be a basis for $\mathcal{H}$. I now want to describe an ensemble of indistinguishable particles (assume bosonic statistic).

In Fock notation, $|N,0\rangle$ describes a state of $N$ particles in $|\psi_A\rangle$, and $0$ particles in $|\psi_B\rangle$ (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fock_space#Product_states,_indistinguishable_particles,_and_a_useful_basis_for_Fock_space)). In this notation the $|NOON\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left(|N,0\rangle+|0,N\rangle\right)$ state is said to be an entangled state (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOON_state)).

Is this true also for $N=1$?

I fail to see which are the two Hilbert spaces in tensor product over which the entanglement is formed. By intuition I would say that this state is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left(|1,0\rangle+|0,1\rangle\right)$, which decribes a single particle in a quantum superposition of $|\psi_A\rangle$ and $|\psi_B\rangle$, i.e.,  $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left(|\psi_A\rangle+|\psi_B\rangle\right)$, which is a pure single particle state, with no entanglement. Isn't this correct?

Comment: entanglement is unrelated to purity.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Not entirely unrelated. The fact that it is pure tells us that it is not entangled with anything else. I agree that it doesn't show that there is no entanglement in the state itself, but that is true due to how I wrote the state $|\psi_A\rangle+|\psi_B\rangle$

Comment: Your comment is wrong in so many ways.  A state like the one you have is basically a Bell state and it is certainly entangled.  It’s easy to work out that it’s also pure: work out $\rho$ in a space spanned by $\vert 11\rangle, \vert 10\rangle, \vert 01\rangle$ and $\vert 00\rangle$ and verify that $\rho^2=\rho$.  The NOON states as you write them are entangled *and* pure for any $N$.

Comment: Pure does not imply not entangled, and entangled does not imply mixed.  It’s somewhat non-trivial to decide if a bipartite state is entangled, but one can always use Peres-Horodecki (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peres%E2%80%93Horodecki_criterion).  In the example provided there, it’s clear that you can have mixed states that are not entangled.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I think you misunderstand my comment. I am not saying that pure implies not entangled. I am just saying that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(|\psi_A\rangle + |\psi_B\rangle\right)$, by being pure, cannot be said to be the partial trace of an entangled system in a larger Hilbert space. I see that the way I wrote the last sentence of my question might be misleading and distracting. I'm open to suggestions on how to change it. I guess I could just replace "is a pure single particle state, with no entanglement" with "does not seem entangled to me".

Comment: A single particle in subsystem $a$ in a superposition would be something like $\alpha \vert 0\rangle_a+\beta\vert 1\rangle_a$.  What also seem to trip you is the $0$ and $1$, which we could replace by spin up or spin down.  Surely this change in notation cannot affect the physics of the entanglement.  If you want to think in terms of occupation number in modes, then your system $\alpha \vert 10\rangle +\beta \vert 01\rangle$ is mode-entangled.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I'm not questioning that a Bell state $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|01\rangle + |10\rangle)$ is entangled. But that is a state of two qubits, with very well defined Hilbert spaces in tensor product. In the case of the NOON state in Fock notation, I have a single particle, described by one qubit (because I've defined the single particle space as $\mathbb{C}^2$). I would like a clear explanation of what Hilbert spaces are in tensor product and why $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|1,0\rangle + |0,1\rangle)$ (Fock notation) is different from $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|\psi_A\rangle + |\psi_B\rangle)$.

Comment: $\vert 10\rangle$ is 2-qubit state (or more appropriately a 2-mode state).  We must be talking at cross-purposes.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero You over-simplify when you say that |01>+|10> is certainly entangled, when |0> and |1> are Fock states. This is only true as long as they describe Fock states of something which does not obey superselection rules (e.g. photons). But with superselection rules (fermions, charged particles, ...), the question becomes rather subtle, and depends on how you define "entangled" (previously equivalent definitions can become inequivalent in the presence of a superselection rule). -- By analogy, for fermions {|0>,|1>} doesn't define a qubit, since superpositions a|0>+b|1> are not admissible.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch. right. Admittedly I was not thinking (at all) along the lines of your comment.

Comment: To me it is not that trivial that $|0,1\rangle$ is a "2-mode state" in the way you probably mean it. From the way I built the Fock space (or rather it is built in the linked wikipedia page), there is no tensor product between the two modes, and therefore I find no trivial way to have entanglement in the $|1001\rangle$ state. One non-trivial way would be to notice that there is an isomorphism between the Fock space I built and the tensor product of two "single-mode" Fock spaces. If the $|1001\rangle$ state of my question is seen in that space through the isomorphism, then there is entanglement.